# spark aggregatebykey - sum and running average in the same call

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning spark, and do not have experience in hadoop.

Problem

I am trying to calculate the sum and average in the same call to aggregateByKey.

Let me share what I have tried so far.

**Setup the data**

```
val categoryPrices = List((1, 20), (1, 25), (1, 10), (1, 45))
val categoryPricesRdd = sc.parallelize(categoryPrices)
```

**Attempt to calculate the average in the same call to  aggregateByKey. This does not work.**

```
val zeroValue1 = (0, 0, 0.0) // (count, sum, average)
categoryPricesRdd.
    aggregateByKey(zeroValue1)(
        (tuple, prevPrice) => {
            val newCount = tuple._1 + 1
            val newSum = tuple._2 + prevPrice
            val newAverage = newSum/newCount
            (newCount, newSum, newAverage)
    },
    (tuple1, tuple2) => {
        val newCount1 = tuple1._1 + tuple2._1
        val newSum1 = tuple1._2 + tuple2._2
        // TRYING TO CALCULATE THE RUNNING AVERAGE HERE
        val newAverage1 = ((tuple1._2 * tuple1._1) + (tuple2._2 * tuple2._1))/(tuple1._1 + tuple2._1)
       (newCount1, newSum1, newAverage1)
    }
).
collect.
foreach(println)
```

Result: Prints a different average each time

- First time: (1,(4,100,70.0))
- Second time: (1,(4,100,52.0))

**Just do the sum first, and then calculate the average in a separate operation. This works.**

```
val zeroValue2 = (0, 0) // (count, sum, average)
categoryPricesRdd.
    aggregateByKey(zeroValue2)(
        (tuple, prevPrice) => {
            val newCount = tuple._1 + 1
            val newSum = tuple._2 + prevPrice
            (newCount, newSum)
        },
        (tuple1, tuple2) => {
            val newCount1 = tuple1._1 + tuple2._1
            val newSum1 = tuple1._2 + tuple2._2
            (newCount1, newSum1)
        }
    ).
    map(rec => {
        val category = rec._1
        val count = rec._2._1
        val sum = rec._2._2
        (category, count, sum, sum/count)
    }).
    collect.
    foreach(println)
```

Prints the same result every time:
(1,4,100,25)

I think I understand the difference between [seqOp and CombOp](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions). Given that an operation can split data across multiple partitions on different servers, my understanding is that seqOp operates on data in a single partition, and then combOp combines data received from different partitions. Please correct if this is wrong.

However, there is something very basic that I am not understanding. Looks like we can't calculate both the sum and average in the same call. If this is true, please help me understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation related to your `average` aggregation in `seqOp`:

```
val newAverage = newSum/newCount
```

and in `combOp`:

```
val newAverage1 = ((tuple1._2 * tuple1._1) + (tuple2._2 * tuple2._1)) / (tuple1._1 + tuple2._1)
```

is incorrect.

Let's say the first three elements are in one partition and the last element in another.  Your `seqOp` would generate the (count, sum, average) tuples as follows:

```
Partition #1: [20, 25, 10]
  --> (1, 20, 20/1)
  --> (2, 45, 45/2)
  --> (3, 55, 55/3)

Partition #2: [45]
  --> (1, 45, 45/1)
```

Next, the cross-partition `combOp` would combine the 2 tuples from the two partitions to give:

```
((55 * 3) + (45 * 1)) / 4
// Result: 52
```

As you can see from the above steps, the `average` value could be different if the ordering of the RDD elements or the partitioning is different.

Your 2nd approach  works, as `average` is by definition total sum over total count hence is better calculated after first computing the sum and count values.